# javascript dynamically populate associative array and get values

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to build an associative array based on an array and then get the values of that associative array.
The structure of the associative array is as follows:

```
        var myAssociativeArr = new Array();

        myAssociativeArr = [
         { id:'1',
          lname:'doe',
          fname:'john' 
        },
         { id:'2',
          lname:'smith',
          fname:'john' 
        }

        ]
```

I have three arrays of the same length from which I will build this associative array i.e. id, lname and fname array.

```
    for(var i=0; idArray.length;i++)
    {
    myAssociativeArr [id]=idArray[i];
    myAssociativeArr [lname]=lnameArray[i];
    myAssociativeArr [fname]=fnameArray[i];
    }
```

Please tell me if the above approach is correct, if not how can I build this array and also how can I get the values of this array via a loop.

Your help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You are very close. First of all, if you wish to use the array subscript notation, you have to pass the keys themselves (strings in your case, like this):

```
var myAssociativeArr = [];
for (var i=0; i < idArray.length; i++) {
    var newElement = {};
    newElement['id'] = idArray[i];
    newElement['lname'] = lnameArray[i];
    newElement['fname'] = fnameArray[i];
    myAssociativeArr.push(newElement);
}
```

Where the key names are known strings, it's often preferable to use the completely equivalent notation of object properties:

```
var myAssociativeArr = [];
for (var i=0; i < idArray.length; i++) {
    var newElement = {};
    newElement.id = idArray[i];
    newElement.lname = lnameArray[i];
    newElement.fname = fnameArray[i];
    myAssociativeArr.push(newElement);
}
```

You can be even more concise by using object literals, as you did in your sample output:

```
var myAssociativeArr = [];
for (var i=0; i < idArray.length; i++) {
    myAssociativeArr.push({
        id: idArray[i],
        lname: lnameArray[i],
        fname: fnameArray[i]
    });
}
```

Edit: fixed loop indexing to not be infinite.

You read elements the same way you write them: `myAssociativeArr[i]['id']` etc., or `myAssociativeArr[i].id` etc.

For lookups by ID, it's a good idea to construct an object for this.

```
var myObject = {};
for (var i=0; i < idArray.length; i++) {
    myObject[idArray[i]] = {
        id: idArray[i],
        lname: lnameArray[i],
        fname: fnameArray[i]
    };
}
```

To look up:

```
myObject['2'] // => { id: '2', ... }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, how about getting the values from this associative array.

Comment: @Nomad: He already explained how to access objects with bracket notation (you can read as well as write)

Comment: Thanks a lot Jeremy for your time and effort, really appreciate it.

Comment: Now if i want search for id and pull the respective data how can i do that? For example I want to search for id number 2 and want to get lname and fname and id how will i do that. Thanks

Comment: In this case, it would probably be preferable to construct an object whose keys were the values of `id`. something like: `myObject[idArray[i]] = { id: .... };` inside the for loop, with an empty object `{}` being initialized beforehand. Then you could look up objects by ID in constant time. Answer updated to reflect this.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jeremy, you have been very helpful, thanks a lot for your time and efforts. It's working as expected.

Answer (score 5):

not quite, try this:

```
 for(var i=0; idArray.length; i++)
 {
    myAssociativeArr[i] = {
                           id: idArray[i], 
                           lname: lnameArray[i], 
                           fname: fnameArray[i]
                          };
 }
```

to get the id of the 5th element: `myAossociativeArr[i]['id']`, I'm sure you can figure out the rest from here ;)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, how about getting the values from this associative array.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and effort, really appreciate it.

Comment: Now if i want search for id and pull the respective data how can i do that? For example I want to search for id number 2 and want to get lname and fname and id how will i do that. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
for(var i=0; idArray.length;i++)
    {
    myAssociativeArr [i][id]=idArray[i];
    myAssociativeArr [i][lname]=lnameArray[i];
    myAssociativeArr [i][fname]=fnameArray[i];
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and effort, really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Fast-forward, eight years later, using ECMAScript 2015, we would solve this problem by doing:

```
let assocArr = idArray
.map(x=>{ return {id: x}})
.map((x,index) => Object.assign({lname: lname[index]}, x))
.map((x,index) =>Object.assign({fname: fname[index]}, x) )
.reduce((assoc,obj) => {let target = {};target[obj.id] = obj; return Object.assign(target,assoc) }, {})
```

Or by using reduce only:

```
let assocArr = idArray.reduce((assoc, x, index) => {
  let target = {};
  target[x] = { id: x, lname: lname[index], fname: fname[index] };
  return Object.assign(target, assoc);
}, {});
```

If it were ever needed, a more flexible function that does the kind of things above is:

```
function glue(properties) {
  let propsArrays = Object.entries(properties);
  let lookUp = properties[properties.lookUpKey];
  let propertyArrays = propsArrays.filter(
    ([key, value]) => key !== "lookUpKey"
  );
  return propertyArrays.reduce(
    (assoc, props, index) => {
      let [key, values] = [...props];
      return values.reduce((assoc, prop, j) => {
        let target = {};
        target[key] = prop;
        assoc[lookUp[j]] = Object.assign(target, assoc[lookUp[j]]);
        return assoc;
      }, assoc);
    },
    lookUp.reduce((assoc, id) => {
      assoc[id] = {};
      return assoc;
    }, {})
  );
}
```

You give it an object such as

```
var properties = {id: idArray, lname: lname, fname: fname, lookUpKey: 'id'}
```

And based on the object's property names as well as the lookup array key, and it will glue those properties together as objects in an array. The function turns the properties object into an array of key/value pairs with:

```
let propsArrays = Object.entries(properties);
```

Then it extracts the lookUp keys and the actual properties to glue into their respective arrays:

```
let lookUp = properties[properties.lookUpKey];
let propertyArrays = propsArrays.filter(([key, value]) => key !== "lookUpKey");
```

Then, it uses nested `reduce`s to process the properties into arrays of objects with the right properties. Note that:

```
lookUp.reduce((assoc, id) => {
          assoc[id] = {};
          return assoc;
        }, {})
```

initializes the outermost `reduce` with an object with keys/properties that are the values in the lookup array. The values associated to those keys are just empty objects at the beginning. The innermost `reduce` will then merge the appropriate properties into those objects by using:

```
assoc[lookUp[j]] = Object.assign(target, assoc[lookUp[j]])
```